# buildozer version requires a python-for-android version with AAB (Android App Bundle) support

Tags: python, android, linux, apk, buildozer

how can these problems be solved?
I use Ubunto to install the APK, I use a bulldozer.

I did the work with reference to the video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EupAeyL8zAo).

In the process of working I solved the problem of cython.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue.  Found this today, it might help you out.

> You simply need to uncomment the following line in your buildozer.spec
> and replace *master* with *develop*

```
# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
# p4a.branch = master
p4a.branch = develop
```

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the advice.
Will I get the APK file after the change? Please help me :)

Comment: I made that change and the build got much further.  Then I had a SSL error which is solved by this:  https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/#sslerror-can-t-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available     Afterwards I got an APK when I built with the -debug flag.  But the APK didn't work.  So I am looking at Google Collab and will try Buildozer in that environment.

Comment: Yes, your advice has solved my problem, thank you, it has gone far. I have this problem now :( :

Comment: # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/toko/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:

Comment: try `!sudo apt install build-essential autoconf libtool
2 buildozer -v android debug`  then  `!buildozer android clean`  then  `!buildozer -v android debug`

Comment: Hello, I tried Google Collab yesterday, I got the apk, but I have to test it on Android first. I will inform you of the result.
I have tried too many times on Linux but I can not get the apk file.
Did you get it?

Comment: After many attempts, I tried colab.research.google.com and got the result (APK)   thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Great news,  ... give me an upvote, or tick if you can. : )